# Applying two materials

Tags: materials, transparency

I'm trying to apply two materials to an object -- one of them is a transparent PNG graphic which is supposed to be placed on top of another. What I do is select the object, go into Edit Mode, create a new material slot, select the two, and assign them. However, when I assign the PNG material, the one below it disappears -- I can see inside of my object.

[image]

[image]

Here I have the PNG graphic layered on top of the purple color provided by that second BSDF. However, when I try attaching the image texture to the base color of this BSDF, the texture does not cover the entire face of the object. Instead, it results in what is seen here:

[image]

The face of the object is black, displaying the pattern in a box rather than covering the whole object.

Comment: "...select the two, and assign them" - how do you actually do that? You can only select one material slot at once, not two. And each face of an object can only be assigned with one material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the node setup to lay a semi-transparent PNG over another, tiled image texture material.

[image]

Comment: Congrats - you copied my answer. It is the same setup I did - just with colors instead of shaders. Oh man....‍♂️

Comment: @Chris Well, for whatever reason your setup wasn't working for me. Perhaps I misunderstood along the way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You just need 1 material.

In the shader editor use this node setup and you get what you want:

[image]

UPDATE:

setup with two images:

important: the "upper" image must have pixels with alpha < 1 inside of the png (in my case here the "toppng")

[image]

Comment: Not only does he need just one material, but it's simply not possible to apply more than one material per face in Blender.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You're right that you can apply only a single material to a face at a time, I must have been confused. Unfortunately, your model is not working for me:
- When I connect my alpha node to the Mix shader factor node, my PNG turns black
- My second material is not a BDSF, it is an image texture. I tried creating an additional image texture, along with another BDSF, to connect it, along with the PNG + its own BDSF, to the mix shader. But this does not produce the desired results. Please see the screenshot I attached in my original post.

Comment: @Matthew You have to plug the Alpha from the texture into the Fac input of the Mix Shader node, as Chris has shown in this answer.

Comment: @AlexisKing Almost there!! The thing is, Chris shows an example where the material lying under the PNG is simply a principled BSDF with a base color. In my case, the underlying material needs to be an image texture. When I create an image texture node and connect it to the base color of this second BSDF, I only see the image texture applying to the alpha of the PNG, rather than to the entire face of the object. How do I correct this?

Comment: And why can‘t you plug-in additionally the second image texture before the second BSDF like I did with the first? Is that what u want?

Comment: @chris I added some images above. Let me know if I am doing something incorrectly

Comment: please provide your blend file - it is the safest way to help you

Comment: @chris https://we.tl/t-mEUVmHb2EP

Comment: i updated my answer. unfortunately you did not include your textures...next time before you upload the blend file, please use file-> external data -> pack all into blend

Comment: @Chris. Sorry about that. By "alpha = 0 inside of the png" do you mean the PNG must have pixels that are either 100% opacity or 0% opacity? No in between? That's a little ridiculous. I can't seem to reproduce the results you have shown here. 

The second texture is a normal JPG that looks like cloth. You can use something like this: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/46/dc/2d/46dc2dc3b3d646b2755bd6938a656b81.jpg

Comment: ok, please upload your file again WITH your textures as a wrote in my previous comment so that i can check your textures. maybe the error is in there. No, i just meant that there must be pixels without 100% opacity. Sorry, i updated my answer.

Comment: @Chris Hello, thank you for your help. I managed to figure out what it is. I added my material setup to the original post.

Comment: @Matthew: this site tries to help people who have same problems to quickly solve this. Of course - you don't have to say what the reason was. And of course you don't have to check an answer as correct. But it would be nice - if you know the reason for your problem - if you write an own answer and so others can find your solution too. Because you got help - hopefully you will help others.